# ASP.NET System.Anything is not defined

Tags: asp.net, webforms, namespaces, compiler-errors

I ran Debugging and got a ton of "is not defined" errors in all the namespaces under System. The System and System.Web references are in the References folder.

Trying to back track the things I've changed since the last debug, I reduced my root namespace from the default to a three letter abbreviation. Changing it back didn't do anything. Everything else I've been working on has been individual pages.

Most (not all) of the errors go away if I add Global.System to all the namespaces or if I reduce them to the child namespace. i.e. these don't throw errors:

> Global.System.Web.UI.Page
>
> Page

But this does:

> System.Web.UI.Page

Disclaimer: I'm a .NET novice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You tried closing and reopening Visual Studio, or doing a Full Rebuild?

Comment: A full rebuild I hope will work, but I thought I'd try here first. I did close and reopen the project to no avail. Is there a way to see a log of the last successful build compared with the debugging to see what has changed?

Comment: You can use a decompiler like Refactor or JustDecompile to see what the code looks like in the compiled exe/dll

Comment: Also, did you create another class called Global, perhaps there's a naming conflict

Comment: No Global class or System class in my project. What would cause System to not be seen, but Global.System to be seen? Something must trigger that.

Comment: Do other projects on your machine work? Is this isolated to one project? Have you checked the reference paths?

Comment: Other projects work. System reference path is "C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.0\System.dll" That file is there and unchanged since the project was created.

Comment: You tried temporarily removing code, a little at a time until it compiles?

Comment: I didn't have a ton of code. Just the membership provider really. It's a simple site. I created a new project and pasted in all the code and it works fine. It would be nice to know what triggers that behavior, but I need to finish the project and don't have time to play detective.

Comment: understand completely, sometimes that is the best solution, good luck with the rest of the project

Comment: I wasn't aware of the "Full Rebuild" option and instead manually rebuilt the solution and ran it. Had I been aware that you can click a button to do that, that probably would have worked. Deleting the bin folder contents might have worked as well.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have a class named "System"?  Or "Global"?

Comment: No. To be honest, there's very little I have done on the code side.  The only custom class I made is a custom membership provider.

Comment: The reason I asked is that I was using Subsonic a while ago, and I had just gotten a new DB schema from a guy I was working with.  I applied it an regenerated the DB classes.  All of a sudden, VS lit up with red wavy lines EVERYWHERE.  Nothing was resolving.  Turns out, my partner had made a table called "System" and Subsonic happily created a class called System.  VS does not like that.  Not at all.

Comment: I did a search for "Global" and "System" across the entire project and didn't get any class names with it, generated or manually typed. The project solves as long as I add Global to the namespaces. Oddly, I don't need to do this with Imports. Just in the routines themselves.

Comment: I didn't mean to imply that you MUST have a class named System somewhere -- I was just letting you know why I originally posted the suggestion above, and also I think it's kind of funny.