# MVC conversion project, fully qualified classes are not available unless 'Global' is added or System... is removed

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-4

My question is similar to here: [ASP.NET System.Anything is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10509010/asp-net-system-anything-is-not-defined)

I am in the process of converting a website project to an MVC 4 project.  To do this, I created a new MVC project and imported all of my content from the previous website.  Both projects are in VB, and I'm using Visual Studio 2010 SP1, with both the MVC 4 update and TFS 2012 update applied.

I now have errors popping up when I build the MVC project.  Things like "Type 'System.Web.UI.Webcontrol' is not defined."  When I hover over the error, two of the prompts I get to fix it are

1) Change 'System.Web.UI.WebControl' to 'Global.System.Web.UI.WebControl'
2) Change 'System.Web.UI.WebControl' to 'WebControl'

Both of these seem to fix it, but does anyone know why I can't use "System.Web.UI.WebControl" to refer to this class?  I'd rather not change all of my code... there are 100s of thousands lines in there.

Update:  Outside of the System and System.Web.UI namespaces, I can also drop the 'System.'.  So 'System.Drawing.Color' would become 'Drawing.Color'.

Comment: You probably have your own namespace/class called `System` that's closer to the code you're writing than the framework's one.

Comment: No, I don't.  I've worked with this code for years and there is no class with that name from my own code base.

Comment: This is coming from a vb asp.net website project in .net 4.0 that works as-is, by the way.

Comment: what framework are you converting from?

Comment: Have you deleted all references and re-added them, or verified where they are coming from?  It would also help to just make a new project, import only one piece of content with a web control, and see if you get the same error.  You can also check the Web.config in Views to see if it is importing the namespace

Comment: In which type of files you are getting this errors? ASPX or code behind? Or your library code?

Comment: @AndrewBacker I did go through references step-by-step, and I even removed some namespaces that appended to others.  E.g., I had a customcontrols namespace as `System.Web.UI.WebControls.CustomControls`, but changing that to just `customcontrols` didn't fix it.

Comment: @AkashKava, it appears to only be a problem with the code that was previously in the App_Code directory in the website project.  When I moved the project files into an MVC project, I placed all App_Code files into a folder called "Library."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I posted this question before I had whittled down as much of the compile errors as possible.

It appears that after I had removed all the `System.` references from the previous App_Code classes, the real errors started appearing.  There were all sorts of messages about aspx controls not existing.

Ultimately, it seemed that I needed to right-click on the .aspx pages from my website project and choose 'Convert to Web Application.'  This generated a .aspx.designer.vb file with the asp.net control declarations in yet another partial class.

After doing that for all pages, I am now able to use `System.` throughout the app.

To others who've asked, this `System.` error was only affecting the non-page code.  .aspx, .aspx.vb, .ascx, .ascx.vb, .ashx, etc., files were not affected.

This does make some sense, anyhow, as I had previously pulled in all the App_Code libraries prior to pulling in the pages, and the site compiled.  After importing the pages and their code behinds, the order of the errors was just odd.  But I stuck with it and found the underlying cause.

Thanks for the willingness to help.  If you have any other questions, I'd be glad to respond.

Answer (score 0):

There exists another namespace containing `System` in your solution somewhere (e.g. `Abc.System.def`) - probably in a referenced library.  After the conversion, the project file probably imported the prefix to `System` in said namespace (e.g. `Abc`), so when you type in `System`, it resolves to `Abc.System`.

Comment: The funny thing is that the .aspx code behinds do not have the same issue, only the stuff that used to reside in app_code